# Different request types: trait Request takes type parameters

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I tried to duplicate the example given in the documentation for Play 2.2.1:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaActionsComposition

```
import play.api.mvc._

class RequestWithItem[A](val item: Item, request: Request[A])
extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

def ItemAction(itemId: String) = new ActionBuilder[RequestWithItem] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (RequestWithItem[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
    ItemDao.findById(itemId).map { item =>
      block(new RequestWithItem(item, request))
    } getOrElse {
      Future.successful(NotFound)
    }
  }
}

def tagItem(itemId: String, tag: String) = ItemAction(itemId) { request =>
  request.item.addTag(tag)
  Ok
}
```

but I get the compile error:

```
trait Request takes type parameters
```

for the `request.item.addTag(tag)` method.

What would the type parameters be exactly?

Comment: Which line has that error?